# Text to speech is not working

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I want to use text to speech in my app, I have this code

using tutorial from here http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-text-to-speech-tutorial/

```
package voice;

import java.util.Locale;
import android.content.Context;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.util.Log;

public class CustomTTS implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

    private Boolean isReady = false;
    private TextToSpeech tts;

    public CustomTTS(Context context) {
        this.tts = new TextToSpeech(context, this);
    }

    public Boolean isReady() {
        return isReady;
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

            int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
            } else {
                isReady = true;
                speakOut("Hello");
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
        }
    }

    public void speakOut(String text) {
        if (isReady) {
            tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
    }

    public void end() {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
}
```

But it is not working. This is a separate class from the activity class. In the activity class, I create an instance of the above class. When I create it, it should automatically say "hello" when it inits. But when I test on my phone, I don't hear anything...

I am testing on jellybean 4.1.2.

Does anyone know whats wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Have you installed the TTS data for this language?

Comment: Its in settings under text to speech.

Comment: hmm, i think i have english canada, but its still going into the speak function....

Comment: You should speak outside onInit method.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can't start speak onInit method.
You will be able to do so after onInit returns and textToSpeech has been initialized correctly.

**For example you can put a button in your layout and onClick you can speak what you want and the engine will work fine.**

```
m_btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View argView) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        speakOut("Hello");
    }
});
```